# TSQL - Check if exists

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Unfortunately, I have again major problems with a query or with understanding the solution. I've already tested subqueries and an IF EXISTS statement but unfortunately it didn't work

I am  looking for the number of events where a vehicle has stopped but has not arrived - i.e. while the drive was canceled

I have a test table that looks like this:

| cdts | eventnumber | vehicle | status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-10-01 16:15 | ev00001 | vehicle1 | onway |
| 2021-10-01 16:35 | ev00001 | vehicle1 | arrived |
| 2021-10-01 16:45 | ev00002 | vehicle3 | onway |
| 2021-10-01 16:50 | ev00002 | vehicle3 | arrived |
| 2021-10-01 17:04 | ev00003 | vehicle4 | onway |
| 2021-10-01 17:06 | ev00003 | vehicle5 | onway |
| 2021-10-01 17:10 | ev00003 | vehicle5 | arrived |
| 2021-10-01 17:11 | ev00003 | vehicle1 | onway |
| 2021-10-01 17:13 | ev00003 | vehicle3 | onway |
| 2021-10-01 17:18 | ev00003 | vehicle3 | arrived |

Operations:
Different / several vehicles can drive to an event, they have the same event number
Im using SQL Server, TSQL

The output should look like this

| Count Unit Cancel |
| --- |
| 2 |

.

Ive tried already a subquery but i dont know how to get the logic right on this. Or is an if exists statement the best way ?

Im to ashamed to post my trys xD

Thanks a Lot for your Help

Comment: You need to be much clearer about the logic. What happens if it's a different `eventnumber` but the same `vehicle`? What happens if it's `arrived` but hasn't been `onway`? What happens if a `vehicle` was `onway` multiple times to the same `eventnumber`?

Comment: sorry , sure they can be different event number with the same vehicle , its like an dispatch software for  a small company. It should not be possible to arrived without an onway . And if an vehicle is onway multiple times and doesnt arrive , then it should count every time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LEAD` to identify `onway` rows which are not immediately followed by `arrived`. Then simply count those rows:

```sql
SELECT
  [Count Unit Cancel] = COUNT(IsNotArrived)
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      IsNotArrived = CASE WHEN LEAD(status) OVER (PARTITION BY vehicle, eventnumber
                    ORDER BY cdts) = 'arrived' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE status = 'onway';
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=03a3674a3ca46899c3590c22e6ffcb99)

Comment: Perfect, that should work. Could it be that this solution is very resource intensive? The query takes an unusually long time for me (over <20,000) records.

Comment: You would need an index `(vehicle, eventnumber, cdts) INCLUDE (status)` to make this perform well (no need for the `INCLUDE` if it's a clustered index)

Answer (score 1):

This might be an over-simplification, but it appears you are just expecting each "onway" to have a corresponding "arrived" and just what the count of the difference

```
select 
  Sum(case when status='onway' then 1 end) 
  - Sum(case when status='arrived' then 1 end) CountUnitCancel
from t
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy way with antisemijoin technique:

```
-- get all vehicles onway (=not yet arrived)
select count(t1.vehicle) as [Vehicle count onway]
from [table] as t1
left join table2 as t2
    on t1.vehicle = t2.vehicle
    and t1.cdts > t2.cdts
    and t2.[status] = 'arrived'
where t1.[status] = 'onway'
    and t2.vehicle is null
```

The same with exists statement:

```
-- get all vehicles onway (=not yet arrived)
select count(t1.vehicle) as [Vehicle count onway]
from [table] as t1
where not exists (
    select 2
    from table2 as t2
        on t1.vehicle = t2.vehicle
        and t1.cdts > t2.cdts
        and t2.[status] = 'arrived')
where t1.[status] = 'onway'
```

Comment: thanks for your help, but why you use t1.cdts = t2.cdts - the different status are not the same timestamp

Comment: to get only lead records (filter to only previous, not followed records), but its much faster than lead window function